# Socket getOutputStream takes too long

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https

```
Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), 5000);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); // this takes too long
```

The `connect` method returned immediately, but `getOutputStream` stuck for too long.

It is not always too long just for some socket address
For HTTPS (port 443) `getOutputStream()` worked well but for HTTP (port 80) it stuck

Comment: how long is tooooo long?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Very long that I had to stop the program

Comment: *It is not always too long just for some socket address* - firewall issue?

Comment: @Scary Wombat I don't know I'm trying to connect to a http server on port 80, and actually i'm using ```SSLSocket``` instead of ```Socket```. When I try 443 port for https then ```getOutputStream``` worked well, but I don't think ```Socket``` or ```SSLSocket``` is a problem

Comment: @EJP I have debugged that I'm sure ```connect``` returned immediately

Comment: @EJP Does ```connect``` do SSL handshake? I'm using Android Studio I don't know how to set ```-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake```. I have tried debug but it was  strange that I could not step into the ```getOutputStream```, it was stuck when I clicked "step into"

Comment: No. The first I/O does the handshake. Maybe `getOutputStream()` does too.

Answer (score -1):

> For HTTPS (port 443) getOutputStream() worked well but for HTTP (port 80) it stuck

With an `SSLSocket`? Be serious. Port 80 is plaintext. It won't respond to an SSL handshake, at least not as expected. I'm surprised you didn't get a handshake exception.

Use a plaintext socket for HTTP, and SSL for HTTPS. Actually you should use `HttpURLConnection` for both and stop trying to roll your own.

Comment: I thought there should be an exception so that I know the target socket address is not an SSL socket. But there was no exception it just stuck

Comment: I have solved the problem by calling ```socket.setSoTimeout(5000)```

Comment: What's the server? If it's a home-grown one it may still be trying to read the request line.

Comment: Server is unknown. I'm writing a client to connect my own server, but which server to connect depends on the user input (hostname and port), so I have to determine whether the server is my own server or any other server.

Comment: No you don't. It doesn't make any difference whether it's your server or not. You just have to determine, or ask the user, whether it is HTTP or HTTPS, and use the appropriate socket factory: `javax.net.SocketFactory` or `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.

Comment: Actually I'm writing a server-client based application, I write my own server and client. The user can start server on anywhere, then use the client to connect the server. So it is important to determine whether the target server is my server. (The user may connect to several servers at the same time). Just think about SSH server or something like that. The SSH client has to determine whether the target is an SSH server.

Comment: Which it does by observing the port number, or being told by the user.

Comment: But in my application the user can specify the port for the server. Anyway, by setting ```setSoTimeout``` I can use a socket for  testing the server by handling the exception.